# Filter input paths on nginx-ingress to protect backend

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have a very simple config but didn't find a direct answer yet.
So there is nginx-ingress and gunicorn service behind.
I want to protect gunicorn backend from all the bots bruteforcing urls.
So I want to redirect only few URLs like:

- /
- /one/*
- /two/*
- /three/*

What is the simplest ingress config to achieve this goal?

Comment: You use [kubernetes nginx ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) or [nginxinc kubernetes ingress](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress)? I would say simplest ingress like [here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/v1.8.1/examples/complete-example/cafe-ingress.yaml) should be enough, just add 2 more paths and delete the tls section if you don't use it. Additionally take a look at this [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1120), there are useful informations and few examples.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Partially, the problem is root("/")  allows everything, but I need "/" exactly, and listed urlls with paths, and everything else - forbid.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: app.domain.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /(one|two|three)/
          backend:
            serviceName: app
            servicePort: 5000
        - path: /(.+)
          backend:
            serviceName: app2
            servicePort: 5000
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: app
            servicePort: 5000
```

In this example:

- app - your application
- app2 - application, that responding with 403 or other error